# Integrate Ext.js and jscolor

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am unable to integrate this Javascript color picker into my app. I use the following code:

jscolor installation:

```
<script src="jscolor.js"></script>
Color: <input class="jscolor" value="ab2567">
```

http://jscolor.com/

Ext. js part:

```
xtype: 'component',
    cls: 'jscolor',
    componentCls: 'jscolor',
    html: {
        html: '<input  type= "text" class="jscolor" />'
    },
    itemId: 'colorPicker',
    listeners: {
        afterrender: {
            fn: me.onComponentAfterRender,
            scope: me
        }
    }
},
```

When the form is rendered the input type is not rendered as a color picker. What am I missing here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly where the error came from, but if you want to render only the input (with no field label), I suggest to us `autoEl` config:

```
xtype: 'component',
cls: 'jscolor',
autoEl: {
    tag: "input",
    type: "text"
},
itemId: 'colorPicker'
listeners: {
    afterrender: {
        fn: me.onComponentAfterRender,
            scope: me
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to still have a proper ExtJS field with value, fieldLabel, etc... capabilities, you will have to extend a `Ext.form.field.Base` and see how to add the cls to the `inputEl` (shouldn't be very complicated, you might do this on a afterRender method or change the `inputAttrTpl`).

EDIT:
And it seems you need to call `jscolor.init()` **after the rendering** of you component !!!
EDIT2: 
using ExtJs 4.2, `xtype` is not recognize so you need to create your component with `Ext.create('widget.component, {...})`

Hope it helps

Working Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15q9

Comment: I've edited my answer. See my fiddle, the redesign is good. I did not try myself but seems that you need to call jscolor.init() after the rendering

Comment: In my case is still doesn't get rendered.

Comment: Create a fiddle with your use case so we can dig a little :) (note that I'm using ExtJs 6)

Comment: Maybe the version is the problem. I use Ext 4.2

Comment: Ok simple, see my edited Fiddle! ``Ext.create`` doesn't support ``xtype`` in Ext 4.2

Comment: Did you make it works? (if so, please mark your question as answer :))